# Methods defined as TestMethod do not support Web service callouts

Tags: apex, unit-test, class, callout

i'm not using any web services then also error occur in test class. 
Please help for this :

Apex Class :

```
public class RequestPricingController{
public String oppId{get;set;}
public Opportunity opportunity{get;set;}
public List<SelectOption> SendTypeOptions {get;set;}
public List<SelectOption> FunderQuoteRecordsOptions{get;set;}
public String SelectedSendTypeOptions{get;set;} 
public String SelectedEmailTemplate{get;set;} 
public String SelectedFunderQuoteRecordsOption{get;set;} 
public boolean RecipientsSectionFlag{get;set;}
public map<String,list<Contact>> WrappAccountWithContactMap{get;set;}
public list<RecipientsContactWrapper> recipientsContactWrapperList{get;set;}
public list<Contact> Conlist{get;set;}
public String BankersMessage{get;set;}
public List<SelectOption> EmailTempoptions{get;set;}
public List<String> DocuSignStatusids{get;set;}
public List<attachmentWrapper> attachmentWrapperList{get;set;}
public Attachment attachment{get;set;}
public list<String> uploadedAttachmentids{get;set;}
public boolean NextButtonFlag{get;set;}
public map<String,String> AccountIdsAndOFunderidsMap{get;set;}
public list<Contact> contactList{get;set;}
public boolean ErrorMsgflag{get;set;}

public RequestPricingController(){
    opportunity = new Opportunity();
    ErrorMsgflag = false;
    contactList = new list<Contact>();
    NextButtonFlag = true;
    attachment = new Attachment();
    uploadedAttachmentids = new list<String>();
    EmailTempoptions = new List<SelectOption>();
    WrappAccountWithContactMap = new map<String,List<Contact>>();
    RecipientsSectionFlag = false;
    oppId = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('oppId');
    SelectedSendTypeOptions = '';
    SendTypeOptions = new List<SelectOption>();
    FunderQuoteRecordsOptions = new List<SelectOption>();
    FunderQuoteRecordsOptions.add(new SelectOption('NONE','Select'));
    FunderQuoteRecordsOptions.add(new SelectOption('Yes','Yes'));
    FunderQuoteRecordsOptions.add(new SelectOption('No','No'));
    if(oppId == '' && oppId == null){
        Cancel();
    }
    opportunity = [select id ,name ,Funding_Request_Message_to_Bankers__c from opportunity where id =: oppId ];

    Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = Contact.Send_Type_Default__c.getDescribe();
    List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();
    SendTypeOptions.add(new SelectOption('NONE','Select'));
    for(Schema.PicklistEntry f : ple){
        SendTypeOptions.add(new SelectOption(f.getLabel(), f.getValue()));
    }
    EmailTempoptions.add(new SelectOption('NONE','Select'));
    for(EmailTemplate et :[Select Name,Id ,subject ,body From EmailTemplate  where Folder.Name = 'Funder Template Folder' limit 10000]){
        EmailTempoptions.add(new SelectOption(et.Id,et.Name));
    }  


    getFunderQuoteRecords();
    /*String sQuery;
    for(String field : Contact.sObjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap().keySet()){
        if(sQuery == null)
            sQuery = field;
        else
            sQuery = sQuery + ',' +field;
    }
    sQuery = 'select ' + sQuery + ' accountid,account.name ,account.type from contact where account.type = '+'\'Banker\''+' limit 10000';
    */

    for(Contact con :[select id, name ,Owner.Firstname,Lastname,Send_Type_Default__c, Title,Phone,email,accountid,account.name ,account.type from contact where account.type = 'Banker' limit 10000]){
        contactList.add(con);
    }

    for(Contact con : contactList){
        if(WrappAccountWithContactMap.containskey(con.account.name)){
            Conlist = WrappAccountWithContactMap.get(con.account.name);
            Conlist.add(con);
            WrappAccountWithContactMap.put(con.account.name,Conlist);

        }else{
            Conlist = new list<Contact>();
            Conlist.add(con);
            WrappAccountWithContactMap.put(con.account.name,Conlist);
        }
    }


}
public PageReference setSendType() {
    recipientsContactWrapperList = new list<RecipientsContactWrapper>();
    for(String accName : WrappAccountWithContactMap.keyset()){
        RecipientsContactWrapper wp = new RecipientsContactWrapper();
        List<ContactWrapper> contactWrapperList = new List<ContactWrapper>();
        for(Contact c : WrappAccountWithContactMap.get(accName)){
            ContactWrapper conwrap = new ContactWrapper();
            conwrap.contact = c;
            system.debug(SelectedSendTypeOptions+'<----***********\n***********--->'+c.Send_Type_Default__c);
            if(SelectedSendTypeOptions == c.Send_Type_Default__c && c.email  != '' && c.email != null){
                conwrap.flag = true;
            }else{
                conwrap.flag = false;
            }
            contactWrapperList.add(conwrap);
        }   
        wp.contactWrapper = contactWrapperList;
        wp.accounName = accName;            
        recipientsContactWrapperList.add(wp);
        }
        //DocuSignStatusids.add(oppId);

        fillAttechmentWrapp();

        return null;    
    }
 private void fillAttechmentWrapp(){

    DocuSignStatusids = new List<String>();
    attachmentWrapperList = new List<attachmentWrapper>();
    for(dsfs__DocuSign_Status__c ds: [select id, name from dsfs__DocuSign_Status__c where dsfs__Opportunity__c = :oppId]){
        DocuSignStatusids.add(ds.id);
     }
    for(String s : uploadedAttachmentids){
        DocuSignStatusids.add(s);
    }

    for(Attachment att:[select id, name,ParentId,body  from Attachment where ParentId in: DocuSignStatusids ]){

        attachmentWrapper wap = new attachmentWrapper();
        wap.attachmentFlag = true;
        wap.attachment = att ;
        attachmentWrapperList.add(wap);
    }
 }

 private void getFunderQuoteRecords() {
    AccountIdsAndOFunderidsMap = new map<String,String>();
    for(Funder_Quote__c fq:[Select id , name , Funder__c from Funder_Quote__c limit 10000] ){
        AccountIdsAndOFunderidsMap.put((String)fq.Funder__c,(String)fq.id);
    }
 } 
 public PageReference next() {
    if(SelectedSendTypeOptions != 'NONE' && SelectedFunderQuoteRecordsOption != 'NONE' && SelectedEmailTemplate != 'NONE'){
        RecipientsSectionFlag = true;
        NextButtonFlag = false; 
        setSendType();
    }else{
        ErrorMsgflag = true;
        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Please Select Option'));
    }
    return null;
 }
 public PageReference send() {

    updateOpportunity();
    system.debug('****************'+SelectedFunderQuoteRecordsOption);
    if(SelectedFunderQuoteRecordsOption != 'No')
        CreateFunderQuote();


    EmailTemplate emailTemplate = new EmailTemplate();
    emailTemplate = [Select Name,Id ,subject ,body From EmailTemplate  where id =: SelectedEmailTemplate];

    List<Contact> selectedContactList = new List<Contact>();
    set<Id> selectedContactIdSet = new set<Id>();
    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> sendMassEmail = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>(); 
    List<Id> attachmentIdList = new List<Id>();

    OrgWideEmailAddress oid = [select id, Address, DisplayName from OrgWideEmailAddress limit 1];

    for(attachmentWrapper aw : attachmentWrapperList){
        if(aw.attachmentFlag == true)
            attachmentIdList.add(aw.attachment.Id);
    }

    for(String s : uploadedAttachmentids){
        attachmentIdList.add(s);
    }


    for(RecipientsContactWrapper rcw : recipientsContactWrapperList){
        for(ContactWrapper w : rcw.contactWrapper){
            if(w.flag != false)
                selectedContactIdSet.add(w.contact.id);
        }
    }

    Map<Id,Funder_Quote__c> accountIdFUndingQuoteMap = new Map<Id,Funder_Quote__c>();
    for(Funder_Quote__c fq : [select Id,Funder__c,Name from Funder_Quote__c]){
        accountIdFUndingQuoteMap.put(fq.FUnder__c,fq);
    }
    Schema.DescribeSObjectResult r = Contact.sObjectType.getDescribe();
    Schema.DescribeSObjectResult u = User.sObjectType.getDescribe();
    String sQuery;
    for(String field : Contact.sObjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap().keySet()){
        if(sQuery == null)
            sQuery = field;
        else
            sQuery = sQuery + ',' +field;
    }
    sQuery = 'select ' + sQuery + ',Owner.FirstName,account.name ,account.type from contact where id in : selectedContactIdSet limit 10000';

    system.debug('=====>'+sQuery);
    Messaging.Emailfileattachment efa;
    List<Messaging.Emailfileattachment> efaList = new List<Messaging.Emailfileattachment>();



    for(Attachment at :[SELECT Id, Name, ContentType, Body FROM Attachment WHERE id in:attachmentIdList]){
        efa = new Messaging.Emailfileattachment();
        efa.setFileName(at.Name);
        efa.setBody(at.Body);
        efa.setContentType(at.ContentType);
        efaList.add(efa);
        }

    for(Contact con : database.query(sQuery)){
        String emailbody = emailTemplate.body;
        String emailSubject = emailTemplate.subject;
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        String[] toAddresses = new String[] {con.Email};

        mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
        mail.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(oid.Id);
        emailSubject = emailSubject.replace('{!Funder_Quote__c.Name}',accountIdFUndingQuoteMap.get(con.AccountId).Name);
        mail.setSubject(emailSubject);
        emailbody = emailbody.replace('{!User.FirstName}',con.Owner.FirstName);
        emailbody = emailbody.replace('{!Contact.FirstName}',con.FirstName);
        mail.setSaveAsActivity(true);
        mail.setFileAttachments(efaList );

        if(SelectedFunderQuoteRecordsOption != 'No' && AccountIdsAndOFunderidsMap.containsKey(con.accountid) ){
            mail.setWhatId(AccountIdsAndOFunderidsMap.get(con.accountid));
        }else{
            mail.setWhatId(oppId);
        }


        mail.setPlainTextBody(emailbody);
        mail.setHtmlBody(emailbody);
        sendMassEmail.add(mail);
    }
    Messaging.sendEmail(sendMassEmail);
    delete[select Id from attachment where Id in : uploadedAttachmentids];
    return null;
 }
 public PageReference Cancel() {
    PageReference ReturnPage = new PageReference('/' + oppId);
    ReturnPage.setRedirect(true); 
    return ReturnPage;
 }
 private void updateOpportunity() {
    update opportunity;
    //ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.INFO,'Message updated successfully'));
    //return null;
 }
 private void CreateFunderQuote() {
    set<id> accIds = new set<id>();
    Funder_Quote__c fq ;
    list<Funder_Quote__c> fqList = new list<Funder_Quote__c>();
     for(RecipientsContactWrapper wap :recipientsContactWrapperList){
        for(ContactWrapper w : wap.contactWrapper){
            if(w.flag != false){
                accIds.add(w.contact.accountid);
             }
        }
     }

     for(id aid: accIds){
        if(!AccountIdsAndOFunderidsMap.containskey(aid)){
            fq = new Funder_Quote__c();
            fq.Funder__c = aid;
            fq.Opportunity__c = oppId;
            fq.Submitted_Date__c = System.Today();
            fqList.add(fq);
         }
     }
     insert fqList;
     getFunderQuoteRecords();
 }

  public PageReference upload() {

    attachment.OwnerId = UserInfo.getUserId();
    attachment.ParentId = oppId; 
    attachment.IsPrivate = false;
    //attechment.name= attechment.name;

    try {
      insert attachment;
      uploadedAttachmentids.add(attachment.id);
      fillAttechmentWrapp();
    } catch (DMLException e) {
      ErrorMsgflag = false;
      ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Error uploading attachment'));
      return null;
    } finally {
      attachment = new Attachment(); 
    }

    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.INFO,'Attachment uploaded successfully'));
    return null;
  }




 public class RecipientsContactWrapper{
    public String accounName{get;set;}
    public Boolean flag{get;set;} 
    public list<ContactWrapper> contactWrapper{get;set;}
    public RecipientsContactWrapper(){
        contactWrapper = new list<ContactWrapper>();
    }
 }  

 public class ContactWrapper{   
    public Boolean flag{get;set;} 
    public Contact contact{get;set;}
    public ContactWrapper(){
        contact = new Contact();
    }
 }  

 public class attachmentWrapper{
    public Boolean attachmentFlag{get;set;} 
    public Attachment attachment{get;set;}
    public attachmentWrapper(){
        attachment = new Attachment();
    }
 }
}
```

Test Class :

```
@isTest
private class RequestPricingControllerTest {

static testMethod void myUnitTest() {
    Account account = new Account();
    account.Name = 'test account';    
    insert account;

    Contact  con = new Contact ();
    con.lastName='test1';
    con.AccountId = account.id;
    con.Send_Type_Default__c = 'New Application';
    con.Email = 'test@test.com';
    insert con;


    Opportunity opp = new Opportunity ();
    opp.Name = 'test';
    opp.Accountid = account.id;
    opp.CloseDate = system.Today()+2;
    opp.Potential_Rev__c = 22;
    opp.Contact__c = con.id;
    opp.StageName ='App in';
    insert opp;

    Attachment attach = new Attachment();    
    attach.Name = 'Unit Test Attachment';
    Blob bodyBlob = Blob.valueOf('Unit Test Attachment Body');
    attach.body = bodyBlob;
    attach.parentId = opp.id;
    insert attach; 


    ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('oppId',opp.Id); 
    RequestPricingController rpc = new RequestPricingController();
   // rpc.Cancel();
   // rpc.next();
    //rpc.Upload();
   // rpc.setSendType();


}
}
```

Comment: as I see, you are using DocuSign? Are you sure that there are no callouts there? Also is there any triggers on  Contact, Account , Opportunity? Can there be any callout?

Comment: Check the debug log for more insight; once you find the location, you can mock the callout in your testmethod